# getting error while generating iOS app archive for AFNetworkActivityLogger . rsync error shown in the output logs of archive

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

Showing Recent Issues
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AFNetworkActivityLogger.framework" "/Users/roshnisatyarthi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Illuminex-dfoojhelnrebktgmqukhedzexkci/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VDB-Debug/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/VDB.app/Frameworks"

building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/roshnisatyarthi/Documents/GitHub/illuminex-iPad/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AFNetworkActivityLogger.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)

[[pod file detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD6b9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7hZ4.png)

using latest xcode version v14.3.1, macOs v13.4.1,
COCOAPODS: 1.12.1

Checked related issue on stackoverflow but didn't work. need help to fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.